# Making 2 yubikeys generate the same password

Tags: keepass, yubikey

Is their a way you can make two yubikeys generate the exact same password at the exact same time? (identical copy) I am wanting to purchase two of them so I am able to store a backup yubikey in a secure location just in case I loose the main yubikey.

I am mainly interested in this for SSH keys and Keepass database's

Comment: have you asked Yubikey's support?

Comment: https://www.yubico.com/faq/backup-yubikey/

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a sensible question.

Answer (score 2):

If they were initialized with the same seed and had been through the same number of iterations, it's probably possible.

What you should be doing is registering the two different keys to the same account. Should you lose one, invalidate it.

Comment: Does the iteration matter?

Comment: I just know that google's authenticator has no idea what iteration it's on.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman: Google's Authenticator uses OATH-TOTP, where the current timestamp is used as the "iteration". But Yubikeys (as well as OATH-HOTP) have an incrementing counter, and the validation server actually remembers the last iteration it verified, preventing rollback.